# OpenGL ES error: Mipmapping enabled without a complete mip-chain

Tags: ios, opengl-es

It plays well on iPhone, but showes error when I use the Xcode capture GPU frame tool. There is no texture #0 at all. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's complaining about the texture with ID 0 (in fact I think there will never be a texture with ID 0).

Rather, I think it is complaining about the texture in *slot* 0, i.e. the one you bound to GL_TEXTURE0. In this case it happens to be the texture with ID 1.

Comment: I agree that there will never be a texture with ID 0. And I will never bind a texture 0 to GL_TEXTURE0.

Comment: The error is complaining about the texture with ID 1 which you have bound to GL_TEXTURE0.